# Calculating AdaBoost Training Error from Sklearn

Tags: python, adaboost

I have an adaboost implementation in python that is able to correctly classify my points in the training set.

```
boost = AdaBoostClassifier( base_estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 1, max_leaf_nodes=2), 
                        algorithm = 'SAMME',n_estimators=3, learning_rate=1.0)
```

When I print the final accuracy, I get 1.0

```
boost.score(X,y)
```

When I print the estimator errors

```
boost.estimator_errors_
```

I get an array of: [ 0.25      ,  0.16666667,  0.1       ]

How do I calculate the overall training error of my implementation? I thought it might be the weighted sum of the misclassification rate for each of the three iterations but I can't find a definitive answer. It was a small dataset and I think two points were misclassified at each iteration.

Comment: from the docs: "Return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels". So if you wan't to calculate the average accuracy as a whole you need the number of rows in each label and then multiply  0.25*n_rows_label0+ 0.16666667n_rows_label1 + 0.1*n_rows_label2

Comment: thanks! is training error = 1- accuracy?

Comment: yes,  accuracy is simply the percentage of rows which were correctly classified. so naturally the error is 1-accuracy, being the percentage of rows which were wrongly classified.